# Android Studio won't load database

Tags: android, postgresql

I have a problem loading my PostgreSQL database into my Android app.
I have predefined my database using "DB Browser for SQLite" and moved it to assets/databases folder in my Android project.
When I install the app on the phone, the database is there (checked in Android Studio using View/Tool Windows/Device File Explorer, although it's empty database. If I read correctly, `getReadableDatabase` and `getWriteableDatabase` may create the empty database instead of using the one provided in some cases, I'm not sure why it's doing this in my case.

Any advice is appreciated, here is the code I have in my DataBase helper class (After having the issue for several days I decided to use some tutorial and that's where I got the code from).

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.irek.flashcards/databases/";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "flashCards.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    Cursor c = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if (dbExist){

        }
        else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDatabase();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException sle){
            // Database doesn't exists
        }

        if (checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        // Open local db as an Input stream
        InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length=input.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if (db != null){
            db.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
}
```

I imagine one solution would be to insert all the data inside Android code when the empty database is created, but I don't think that would be easy job to do. I am making Flash Card application which will be supporting multiple languages, at least five - if I add 1000 words per each language it will take me a month to write all the Inserts for it.

Comment: The issue persists regardless of the path being hardcoded or not. As mentioned in my comment, I tried different approach, but since it failed, I used the one from the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I managed to find the root of the problem and the solution to solve it, I've decided to post it here for future reference.

I have created database file (file.db) and placed it within my Android Studio project (I created `assets` folder, within that I created another `databases` folder and that's where I copied my file to). The solution to fix the issue was to move `file.db` one level up and place it within `assets` folder directly.

As it was pointed out before, hardcoding paths is not a best technique and I don't encourage this. My code from above is not perfect, however if you ever have similar issue to mine, this is the solution to solve it.